# does returning from doGet() or doPost() automatically send a resonse

Tags: servlets

I have looked around and previously asked this question but did not get a full answer. When you explicity return from doGet() or doPost() does a response get sent regardless of if you have encoded anything or not. If so what is the default code ? Is it enough to simply `response.setStatus()` and return ? If not: so I have always manually send back a response ? What is the default way to just respond not using forward or redirect ?

Comment: You have to setStatus and depending on what status you send you may have to send a response body.  If you just return status 200, you can get away with not sending a body but a response on the browser will be a blank page.  Read the HTTP RFC to understand more about what this means:  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616

Comment: So when you say response.getWriter()).write is that what sends the response back ? or do you have to forward back to the page ? What mechanism sends the response?

Comment: Yes, set status and write result, that will send things back to clients, make sure you call flush () when done, some implementations don't auto-flush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do nothing, just return (or not even return) from a servlet, it will send back a status code 200(OK) empty response. Tested it in both tomcat and glassfish servers, using the servlet below:

```
@WebServlet("/a")
public class a extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        return;
    }

}
```

Using the network profiler tool of Chrome you can see what I said:

[image: profiler print]